# Android reading a large file

Tags: java, android, database, csv

I have a CSV file in the **assets** folder with more than 10000 lines of data. I want to insert this data into a SQLite database when the database is created. I cannot include a database because it is a very generic application and the model demands a CSV file instead. I don't want to read all 10000 lines of data and insert it from the memory in one stretch. How do I accomplish the task effectively and efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just insert *immediately* once you've read the line. So, just don't store the lines in some arraylist in memory.

E.g.

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    insert(line);
}
```

You might want to do this in a single transaction so that you can rollback whenever it fails halfway. In the JDBC side, you may want to consider `PreparedStatement#addBatch()`/`#executeBatch()` to execute the inserts in batches. An example can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355046/java-insert-multiple-rows-into-mysql-with-preparedstatement/4355097#4355097).

**Update**: as a completely different but more efficient alternative, you can also leave Java outside the story and use [CSV import facility provided by SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki/wiki?p=ImportingFiles).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369325/android-finding-files-on-the-sdcard

Comment: In your update you mention the possbility of importing a CSV file directly into the SQLite database. However I cannot see any Android implementation on the website. Does this facility exist for Android as well?

Answer (score 3):

the simplest and most efficient in this case is to read 20-30-50(or maybe 100?!) lines at a time from the file and insert into the database, however you also need to run a few tests to see what is the best number of lines that you can read in 1 go and then do it :-)

Answer (score 1):

> IMPORT filename tablename

(from http://old.nabble.com/How-can-I-load-big-file-into-a-sqlite-database--td19202500.html - like LOAD DATA in mysql).

Other:
disable auto commit, auto flush; read 20 lines, commit, flush.