# Multiple insert from different threads simultaneously without locking tables?

Tags: mysql, locking, deadlock, database-administration

I am facing issue with mysql table locks. I want to insert multiple records in a table from various threads . On this the first threads which starts inserting data into table acquires table locks and others threads has to wait for the first threads to finish. Which is an overhead for the applications. I want to solve this issue. I want to allow all the threads to insert bulk records at the same time into the same table . Is it possible in mysql , If yes , then how?? Please guide me.

Thanks,

Nitesh Kumar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355046/java-insert-multiple-rows-into-mysql-with-preparedstatement

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your problem is about Isolation Level

Check the connection Isolation Level settings may be it can help

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/dynindex-isolevel.html

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows [`INSERT DELAYED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html). The row is scheduled for insertion and the database call returns. Starting with 5.5.7, it even supports delaying multi-row inserts.