# java sqlite autocommit slow

Tags: java, sqlite, autocommit

Background: I'm working with Java in Netbeans.

I'm reading rows from a CSV file and inserting them into a SQLite database. Very basic stuff I would think. From examples found at this site and elsewhere I've constructed the following code. It works but I'm surprised to see how slow it is. It takes 3.95 seconds to load 46 lines into the db! Using the Netbeans Profiler I can see it's the autoCommit() that's taking the bulk of the time, 3.7 seconds.

What am I doing wrong? Or, is this just the penalty for using SQLite instead of MySQL?

```
      public static void LoadJCNAClassesTable(Connection aConn, String strPath) throws SQLException{
    String [] nextLine;
    String strDivision;
    String strClass;
    String strNotes;
    String strDescription;

    Statement stat = aConn.createStatement(); 
    stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists JCNAClasses;"); 
    String q = "create table JCNAClasses ('ID'  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'division' TEXT NOT NULL, 'class' TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 'description' TEXT NOT NULL, 'note'  TEXT NOT NULL, 'node' INTEGER NOT NULL);";
    stat.executeUpdate(q);
    CSVReader reader;
    int iLine;

    String JCNAClassesCSV = strPath + "\\JCNAClassesCsv.txt" ;

    try {
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(JCNAClassesCSV ));
        iLine = 0;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
        // System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] );
            if (iLine > 0){
                strDivision = nextLine[0];
                strClass = nextLine[1];
                strDescription= nextLine[2];
                strNotes= nextLine[3];
                PreparedStatement prep = aConn.prepareStatement( "insert into JCNAClasses ('division', 'class', 'description', 'note', 'node') values ( ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?);"); 
                prep.setString(1, strDivision); // note that the comma seems not to be a problem
                prep.setString(2,strClass); 
                prep.setString(3,strDescription); 
                prep.setString(4,strNotes); 
                prep.setInt(5,iLine); 
                prep.addBatch(); 
                aConn.setAutoCommit(false); 
                prep.executeBatch(); 
                aConn.setAutoCommit(true); 

            }
            iLine++;
        }
    }    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Entries.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }    
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Entries.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoadSQLiteConcoursDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
  }

    public static void LoadConcoursEntriesTable(Connection aConn,  String strPath) throws SQLException{ 
String [] nextLine;
String strEntryName;
String strClass;
Integer intYear;
String strDescription;
String strOwnerFirst;
String strOwnerLast;
Integer intJCNA;
String strColor;
String strPlate;
Integer intNode;
Long intPersonnel_id;
Long  intJaguar_id;
ResultSet generatedKeys;
String strStatus;
int intPersonnelNode;
ResultSet r;

CSVReader reader;
String q;
int iLine;
PreparedStatement prep;
ResultSet rs;
Statement stat = aConn.createStatement();
//
// Concourse Personnel Table:  Owners, Judges, & Interested parties
//
stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists ConcoursPersonnel"); 
// status:  Owner = "O";  "J"  = Judge;  "OJ" = Owner & Judge;  "IP" = Interested party, e.g., spouse, restorer
q = "create table ConcoursPersonnel ('personnel_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,  'ownerfirst' TEXT NOT NULL, 'ownerlast' TEXT NOT NULL, 'jcna' INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE, 'status' TEXT NOT NULL, 'node' INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE)";
stat.executeUpdate(q);

//
// Concours Jaguar  Table
//
stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists ConcoursJaguars"); 
q  = "create table ConcoursJaguars ('jaguar_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , 'class' TEXT NOT NULL, 'year' TEXT NOT NULL, 'description' TEXT NOT NULL, 'Color' TEXT, 'plate' TEXT, 'node' INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE)";
stat.executeUpdate(q);

//
// Entry  Table ( a Relationship or "link" between Personnel & Jaguars
//
stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists ConcoursEntries"); 
q  = "create table ConcoursEntries (entry_name TEXT NOT NULL, personnel_id INTEGER NOT NULL, jaguar_id INTEGER NOT NULL, UNIQUE (personnel_id, jaguar_id), FOREIGN KEY (personnel_id) REFERENCES ConcoursPersonnel (Personnel_ID), FOREIGN KEY (jaguar_id) REFERENCES ConcoursPersonnel (jaguar_id))";
stat.executeUpdate(q);
String EntriesCSV = strPath + "\\EntriesCsv.txt" ;
strStatus = "O"; // not in the CSV data so set to Owner
try {
    reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(EntriesCSV ));
    iLine = 0;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
        // System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] );
        if (iLine > 0){
            strEntryName = nextLine[0];
            strClass = nextLine[1];
            intYear= Integer.parseInt(nextLine[2]);
            strDescription= nextLine[3];
            strOwnerFirst= nextLine[4];
            strOwnerLast= nextLine[5];
            intJCNA = Integer.parseInt(nextLine[6]) ;
            strColor= nextLine[7];
            strPlate= nextLine[8];
            intNode= Integer.parseInt(nextLine[9]); // Since Jaguars are 1-to-1 with Entries this is used as Node number for both. However, it can't be used for Personnel Node 
            // 
            // Load Owners into Personnel Table
            //
            Statement s = aConn.createStatement();
            r = s.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM ConcoursPersonnel");
            r.next();
            intPersonnelNode = r.getInt("rowcount") +1 ; // Assignes Personnel node numbers as a continuous sequence

            prep = aConn.prepareStatement( "insert into ConcoursPersonnel ('ownerfirst', 'ownerlast', 'jcna', 'status', 'node' ) values ( ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?);"); 
            //prep.setString(1, strEntryName); // note that the comma seems not to be a problem
            prep.setString(1,strOwnerFirst); 
            prep.setString(2,strOwnerLast); 
            prep.setInt(3,intJCNA); 
            prep.setString(4,strStatus); 
            prep.setInt(5,intPersonnelNode); 
            prep.addBatch(); 
            aConn.setAutoCommit(false); // starts transaction
            prep.executeBatch(); 
            aConn.setAutoCommit(true);  // ends transaction 

            aConn.setAutoCommit(false); // starts transaction
            stat = aConn.createStatement();
            generatedKeys = stat.executeQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid()");
            intPersonnel_id = 0L; // won't be used
            if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                intPersonnel_id = generatedKeys.getLong(1);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("No Personnel ID found in LoadConcoursEntriesTable");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            aConn.setAutoCommit(true); // Commits transaction.
            //
            // Load Entry cars into the ConcoursJaguars table
            //
            prep = aConn.prepareStatement( "insert into ConcoursJaguars ('class', 'year', 'description', 'color', 'plate', 'node' ) values ( ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?, ?);"); 
            prep.setString(1,strClass); 
            prep.setInt(2,intYear);
            prep.setString(3,strDescription); 
            prep.setString(4,strColor); 
            prep.setString(5,strPlate);
            prep.setInt(6,intNode);  //                                        
            prep.addBatch(); 
            aConn.setAutoCommit(false); 
            prep.executeBatch(); 
            aConn.setAutoCommit(true); 

            q =  "select jaguar_id from ConcoursJaguars where node == " + intNode + ";";
            rs = stat.executeQuery(q);
            intJaguar_id = rs.getLong("jaguar_id");

            prep = aConn.prepareStatement( "insert into ConcoursEntries (entry_name, personnel_id, jaguar_id) values ( ?,  ?, ?);"); 
            //prep.setString(1, strEntryName); // note that the comma seems not to be a problem
            prep.setString(1,strEntryName); 
            prep.setLong(2,intPersonnel_id); 
            prep.setLong(3,intJaguar_id);
            prep.addBatch(); 
            aConn.setAutoCommit(false); 
            prep.executeBatch(); 
            aConn.setAutoCommit(true); 
        }
        iLine++;
    }
}    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Entries.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }    
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Entries.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoadSQLiteConcoursDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Setting autoCommit to true is actually executes commit within the loop. Thus, there is no batch operation running: you commit every time you iterate through the loop. To have a batch operation you need to:

1. add `aConn.setAutoCommit(false);` before your `while` operator
2. remove lines wrapping `prep.executeBatch();` (i.e., `aConn.setAutoCommit(false);` and `aConn.setAutoCommit(true);`)
3. move `prep.executeBatch();` out of your loop
4. add line with `aConn.commit();` right after your while loop

```
    aConn.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement prep = aConn.prepareStatement( "insert into JCNAClasses ('division', 'class', 'description', 'note', 'node') values ( ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?);");
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
       if (iLine > 0){
       // some preparations go here
       prep.addBatch();
       }
       iLine++;
    }
    prep.executeBatch();
    aConn.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating your PreparedStatement everytime you go through your loop. This should be moved to just before the while loop.

Also the setAutoCommit option should be set once outside the loop, and then you commit your statements when you hit a reasonable ceiling or when you are done.

You can see an example posted here: [Java: Insert multiple rows into MySQL with PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355046/java-insert-multiple-rows-into-mysql-with-preparedstatement)

Comment: This solves the problem for building the single table I gave, but I have other tables with with relations. In particular, I have a CSV files for what I call "Entries" (as in a car show), where each entry has an Owner and one or more Cars. I want to have the Cars in one table and Owners in another, with a link table called Entries. I'm building these 3 tables all inside a single loop, sweeping through the Entries.csv file. In this situation I can't skip executeBatch() in the Owner & Car tables because if they aren't done I won't have the foreign keys for inserting into the Entries table.

Comment: Can you add the 3 tables and their relations plus the format of the CSV files to your question?

Comment: I've added the code for LoadConcoursEntriesTable() which creates the Personnel table, the Juguars table, then the Entries link table. The format of the CVS file is evident in the code, but I can provide the file itself if you would like. It's 41 rows.

Comment: Still no solution for the second issue, i.e., building the link table fast as one would expect. I can live with what I'm doing since I shouldn't have to load my tables from CSV once I get the whole application into Java. If anyone knows how to do it better I'd sure like to hear about it. email me at jag_mab653@sbcglobal.net since I don't visit this forum often. TIA