# Java: Insert batched data in MySQL database with Prepared Statements

Tags: java, mysql, database, prepared-statement, batch-processing

I have created a custom function to insert data in my MySQL database. The functions first creates a query based on the input given. The query wil look like `INSERT INTO tableName (columnName1, ..., columnNamei) VALUES (?, ..., ?), ..., (?, ...,?)`. After that, the PreparedStatement needs to made, which contains the real values. These need to be added to a batch, because I want to add multiple rows at once (as showed here: [Java: Insert multiple rows into MySQL with PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355046/java-insert-multiple-rows-into-mysql-with-preparedstatement)). Here is the code:

**insertData() Function**

```
public static void insertData(String table, List<HashMap<String, Object>> list) throws SQLException {

    //Create query: make sure all of the rows in the table get the same amount of values passed
    //Prepare colnames string
    String colNamesParsed = "";
    int counter = 1;

    //Iterate over only the first hashmap of the list (THATS WHY ALL THE ROWS NEED TO HAVE THE SAME AMOUNT OF VALUES PASSED)
    for (String colName : list.get(0).keySet()) {

        //Check if it is the last col name
        if (counter != list.get(0).keySet().size()) {
            colNamesParsed = colNamesParsed + colName+", ";
        }
        else {
            colNamesParsed = colNamesParsed + colName;
        }

        counter++;
    }

    //Now create the place holder for the query variables
    String queryVariablesPlaceholder = "";
    int rowSize = 0;
    for (HashMap<String, Object> row : list) {

        //This part is to check if all row sizes are equal
        if (rowSize == 0) {
            rowSize = row.values().size();
        }
        else {
            //Check if the rowsize is equal for all rows
            if (row.values().size() != rowSize) {
                System.out.println("The rows of the arrays are from a different size");
                return;
            }
        }

        String queryVariablesRow = "(?, ";
        for (int j = 1; j < (row.values().size()-1); j++) {
            queryVariablesRow = queryVariablesRow+"?, ";
        }
        queryVariablesRow = queryVariablesRow+"?)";

        //Make sure the query does not start with a comma
        if (queryVariablesPlaceholder.equals("")) {
            queryVariablesPlaceholder = queryVariablesRow;
        }
        else {
            queryVariablesPlaceholder = queryVariablesPlaceholder+", "+queryVariablesRow;
        }
    }

    //The MySQL query needs to be built now
    String query = "INSERT INTO "+table+" ("+colNamesParsed+") VALUES "+queryVariablesPlaceholder+";";
    System.out.println(query);

    //Init prepared statement
    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);

    for (HashMap<String, Object> map : list) {

        int varCounter = 1;
        //Iterate over all values that need to be inserted
        for (Object object : map.values()) {

            if (object instanceof Integer) {
                statement.setInt(varCounter, Integer.parseInt(object.toString()));
            }
            else if (object instanceof String) {
                statement.setString(varCounter, object.toString());
            }
            else if (object instanceof Timestamp) {
                statement.setTimestamp(varCounter, parseStringToTimestamp(object.toString()));
            }
            else if (object instanceof Double) {
                statement.setDouble(varCounter, Double.parseDouble(object.toString()));
            }
            System.out.println(varCounter);
            varCounter++;
        }

        //Add row to the batch
        try {
            statement.addBatch();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    //Execute the query, which is in fact the batch
    statement.executeBatch();
}
```

When I want to insert some data in the database, I execute the following code:

**Functional part**

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object object : listOfObjects) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("columnName1", object.getSomeValue());
        /....../
        map.put("columnName2", object.getSomeOtherValue());

        list.add(map);
    }

    Functions.insertData("tableName", list);
```

Creating the dynamic query seems to work perfectly. However, I can't get the `statement.addBatch()` to work. It keeps giving me the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 9
```

I don't get it, because I only have 8 parameters to pass in every unit of the batch. My target table has 9 columns, so I tried to add a value for that column, but then it says: `No value specified for parameter 10`, so it seems like it isn't closing the 'batch unit' or something.

What am I missing here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might want to read on batch statements (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784197/efficient-way-to-do-batch-inserts-with-jdbc) for example)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RC. If I add `statement.clearParameters()`, I get this error: `java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1`. So does not change the situation. Furthermore, I think my code is the same as mentioned in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
INSERT INTO tableName (columnName1, ..., columnNamei) VALUES (?, ..., ?), ..., (?, ...,?)
```

is not standard SQL syntax. 
If you use this JDBC will a parameter for each "?" in your query.

Use:

INSERT INTO tableName (columnName1, ..., columnNamei) VALUES (?, ..., ?)

and add every statement to a batch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In this example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355046/java-insert-multiple-rows-into-mysql-with-preparedstatement) there is stated that I am using a standard SQL syntax.

Comment: I figured it out with this: I had based my code on this example: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/, from which I concluded that I would need multiple (?,?,?....?). For the batch functionality, only one is sufficient. Can anyone tell me why this is the case?

Comment: When you use batch update + PreparedStatement, what happens is: 
1. The SQL is compiled only one, and not on every execution. This is 1 time saver;
2. All the inserts are send to the database and executed in bulk, which means it does not use the cycle send statement + execute it + return the result/errors to the client. This is another time saver. 
It is basically the equivalent for the INSERT with multiple (?, ..?), even in performance.

Comment: Very well explained! I totally get it now and I understand that I mixed up two different techniques.

Comment: Maybe it could be useful to emphasize this difference in your answer as well, to be able to help other people that struggle with this too.