# Does mysql client/server protocol supports batch inserts

Tags: mysql

I need to execute large amount of the `inserts` to the mysql table over mysql client/server protocol via [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/prepared-statements.html). How to do it better? Is there only one way to do it to build a query, something like this:

```
insert into my_table (?, ?), VALUES (1,2), (..., ...)....
```

and send it or maybe mysql client/server protocol support batch inserts? I've found [COM_STMT_SEND_LONG_DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-stmt-execute.html#packet-COM_STMT_EXECUTE) in the mysql documentation, but I'm not sure that it is what i need.

I saw example on java: [Java: Insert multiple rows into MySQL with PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355046/java-insert-multiple-rows-into-mysql-with-preparedstatement) and there is `addBatch` method. Does this method just builds one `insert` request with many `VALUES` clauses or it uses something from the mysql protocol?

Thank you.

Comment: [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

MySQL server supports batch inserts, yes. You can do it like that:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(10,11,12);
```

Comment: What if i need to execute 1K inserts, 10K inserts?

Comment: I think that the limit is 1 million inserts, but that can be changed somehow, if you want even more.

Comment: max_allowed_packet is the variable that puts an upper bound on the size of your query. The actual query limit will be slightly less due to the protocol overhead.  Default is 16M, you can set it locally per connection with ```set max_allowed_packet=<number_of_bytes>``` from your client code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

insert into `members`(`memberID`,`CompanyName`,`Location`) values 
(1,'John Doe','Pittsburgh'),
(2,'Jane Sikes','New York'),
(3,'Bob Smith','Los Angeles');