# insert 5 rows of data in the database using servlet and jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I want to insert 5 rows of data in mysql database. I know how to do it for 1 row at a time but I dont know how to send more than one row.

timesheet.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>  
    <head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
         function updateHours(row){ 
            var $date = row.find('[name="date"]');
            var $time1 = row.find('[name="logintime"]');
            var $time2 = row.find('[name="logouttime"]');
            var $time3 = row.find('[name="lunch"]');
            var $time4 = row.find('[name="afterlunchlogin"]');
            var $time5 = row.find('[name="afterlunchlogout"]');
            var $diff = row.find('.totalTime');
            var $over = row.find('.overTime');

                    if($time1.val() && $time2.val() && $time3.val() && $time4.val() && $time5.val())
            {   
                 var dateInput = $date.val();
                var dtStart = new Date(dateInput + " " + $time1.val());
                var dtEnd = new Date(dateInput + " " + $time2.val());
                var dtLunch= new Date(dateInput + " " + $time3.val());
                var dtStartafterlunch = new Date(dateInput + " " + $time4.val());
                var dtEndafterlunch = new Date(dateInput + " " + $time5.val());

                var diff = ((dtEnd - dtStart)+(dtEndafterlunch-dtStartafterlunch)) / 1000;

                var totalTime = 0;
                var overTime = 0;

                if (diff > 60*60*8) {

                    overTime = formatDate(diff - 60*60*8);
                } else {
                    totalTime = formatDate(diff);
                }
                totalTime = formatDate(diff);
                $diff.val(totalTime);
                $over.val(overTime);
            }
        }

        function formatDate(diff){
            var hours = parseInt( diff / 3600 ) % 24;
            var minutes = parseInt( diff / 60 ) % 60;
            var seconds = diff % 60;

            return (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
        }

        $(".start, .end, .lunch, .startafterlunch, .endafterlunch, .totalTime").on("change, keyup", function(){
            debugger
            updateHours($(this).closest('tr'));
        });

    });
         </script>

    <title>Timesheet Page</title>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <header>
            <h2>WEEKLY TIME SHEET MANAGEMENT V 1.0</h2>
        </header>

        <form action="TimeSheet" method="post">
            <fieldset style="width: 90%">  
                <legend>Timesheet</legend>   
                <h2>Time Sheet application</h2>
    <table border=1>
    <tr><th>Employee ID</th><th>Date</th><th>Time In</th><th>Time Out</th><th>Lunch</th><th>After Lunch Time in</th><th>After Lunch Time out</th><th>Task Description</th><th>Total Hours</th><th>Overtime</th> </tr>


        <tr> <td><input type="text" name="empid" required="required" /></td>   
    <td><input type="date" id="date" name="date"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="start" name="logintime"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="end"name="logouttime" /></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="lunch" name="lunch" /></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="startafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogin"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout"/></td>
    <td><input type="textarea" name="task" required="required" /></td>
    <td><input class="totalTime" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td><input class="overTime" readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
        <tr> <td><input type="text" name="empid" required="required" /></td>   
    <td><input type="date" id="date" name="date"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="start" name="logintime"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="end"name="logouttime" /></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="lunch" name="lunch" /></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="startafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogin"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout"/></td>
    <td><input type="textarea" name="task" required="required" /></td>
    <td><input class="totalTime" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td><input class="overTime" readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
        <tr> <td><input type="text" name="empid" required="required" /></td>   
    <td><input type="date" id="date" name="date"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="start" name="logintime"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="end"name="logouttime" /></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="lunch" name="lunch" /></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="startafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogin"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout"/></td>
    <td><input type="textarea" name="task" required="required" /></td>
    <td><input class="totalTime" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td><input class="overTime" readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
        <tr> <td><input type="text" name="empid" required="required" /></td>   
    <td><input type="date" id="date" name="date"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="start" name="logintime"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="end"name="logouttime" /></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="lunch" name="lunch" /></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="startafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogin"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout"/></td>
    <td><input type="textarea" name="task" required="required" /></td>
    <td><input class="totalTime" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td><input class="overTime" readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
        <tr> <td><input type="text" name="empid" required="required" /></td>   
    <td><input type="date" id="date" name="date"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="start" name="logintime"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="end"name="logouttime" /></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="lunch" name="lunch" /></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="startafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogin"/></td>
    <td><input type="time" class="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout"/></td>
    <td><input type="textarea" name="task" required="required" /></td>
    <td><input class="totalTime" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td><input class="overTime" readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
    </table>
            </fieldset>      
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
       <a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a>
    </body>  
    </html>
```

In TimsheetDao.java

```
package com.eis.Dao;
import com.eis.bean.ConnectionProvider;
import com.eis.bean.EmployeeBean;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

    public class TimeSheetDao {
  public static int insert(EmployeeBean eb,String sql) throws Exception {

    int i=0;  
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    System.out.println("In TimesheetDao");
    Connection conn=ConnectionProvider.getConn();  
    try{ 


        System.out.println(" in try in Timesheetdao");

         ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setString(1,eb.getEmpid());
       // ps.setDate(2, (java.sql.Date) eb.getLoginDate());
       // ps.setDate(3, (Date) eb.getLoginTime());  
       // ps.setDate(4, (Date) eb.getLogoutTime());  
        ps.setDate(2,new Date(eb.getLogindate().getTime()));
        ps.setString(3,eb.getLogintime());  
        ps.setString(4,eb.getLogouttime()); 
        ps.setString(5,eb.getLunch());
        ps.setString(6,eb.getAfterlunchlogin());  
        ps.setString(7,eb.getAfterlunchlogout()); 
        ps.setString(8,eb.getTask());
        ps.setString(9,eb.getTotal());
        ps.setString(10,eb.getOvertime());

        i=ps.executeUpdate();  
        /*rs = pst.executeQuery();  
                    status = rs.next(); */
        }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally { 
        if (conn != null) {  
            try {  
                conn.close();  
            } catch (SQLException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }
        if (ps != null) {  
            try {  
                ps.close();  
            } catch (SQLException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  

    }  
    return i;  

}
}
```

In TimeSheetServlet.java

```
    package com.eis.servlet;

    import com.eis.Dao.TimeSheetDao;
    import com.eis.bean.EmployeeBean;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Locale;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    public class TimeSheet extends HttpServlet {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private TimeSheetDao dao;
        public TimeSheet() {
            super();
            dao = new TimeSheetDao();
        }

        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException, ParseException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            EmployeeBean eb = new EmployeeBean();
            String Emp_id=request.getParameter("empid");    
            eb.setEmpid(Emp_id);
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
            Date logindate = new java.sql.Date(formatter.parse(request.getParameter("logindate")).getTime());
            eb.setLogindate((java.sql.Date) logindate);
            String LoginTime=request.getParameter("logintime");
            eb.setLogintime(LoginTime);
            String LogoutTime=request.getParameter("logouttime");   eb.setLogouttime(LogoutTime);
            String Lunch=request.getParameter("lunch"); eb.setLunch(Lunch);
            String AfterLunchLogin=request.getParameter("afterlunchlogin"); eb.setAfterlunchlogin(AfterLunchLogin);
            String AfterLunchLogout=request.getParameter("afterlunchlogout"); eb.setAfterlunchlogout(AfterLunchLogout);
            String TaskDescription=request.getParameter("task"); eb.setTask(TaskDescription);
            String TotalHours=request.getParameter("total");  eb.setTotal(TotalHours);
            String OverTime=request.getParameter("overtime"); eb.setOvertime(OverTime);

            System.out.println(request.getParameter("empid"));
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);  
            try{if (Emp_id!=null){
                session.setAttribute("Emp_id",Emp_id);}
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try{if (logindate!=null){
                session.setAttribute("LoginDate",logindate);}
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try{if (LoginTime!=null){
                session.setAttribute("LoginTime",LoginTime);}
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try{if (LogoutTime!=null){
                session.setAttribute("LogoutTime",LogoutTime);}
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try{if (Lunch!=null){
                session.setAttribute("Lunch",Lunch);}
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try{if (AfterLunchLogin!=null){
                session.setAttribute("AfterLunchLogin",AfterLunchLogin);}
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try{if (AfterLunchLogout!=null){
                session.setAttribute("AfterLunchLogout",AfterLunchLogout);}
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try{if (TaskDescription!=null){
                session.setAttribute("TaskDescription",TaskDescription);}
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try{if (TotalHours!=null){
                session.setAttribute("TotalHours",TotalHours);}
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try{if (OverTime!=null){
                session.setAttribute("OverTime",OverTime);}
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}


            TimeSheetDao dao = new TimeSheetDao();
            System.out.println("before sql");
              String sql= "insert into logintable values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
              System.out.println("after sql");
           try {
               System.out.println("in try servlet after sql");
               int status = TimeSheetDao.insert(eb, sql);

               System.out.println("in try dao after sql");
            if(status!=0){
                out.print("<p style=\"color:Green\">Record saved successfully!!</p>");  
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");    
                rd.include(request,response);
            }
           else{    
                out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">**Record cannot be saved!**</p>");    
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");    
                rd.include(request,response);
            }

             }
           catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }

        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
        /**
         * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            try {
                processRequest(request, response);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TimeSheet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            try {
                processRequest(request, response);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TimeSheet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns a short description of the servlet.
         *
         * @return a String containing servlet description
         */
        @Override
        public String getServletInfo() {
            return "Short description";
        }// </editor-fold>

    }
```

EmployeeBean:

```
package com.eis.bean;

    import java.util.Date;

    public class EmployeeBean {
        private String empid;
        private java.sql.Date logindate;
        private String logintime;
        private String logouttime;
        private String lunch;
        private String afterlunchlogin;
        private String afterlunchlogout;
        private String task;
        private String total;
        private String overtime;

        public String getEmpid() {
            return empid;
        }

        public void setEmpid(String empid) {
            this.empid = empid;
        }

        public java.sql.Date getLogindate() {
            return logindate;
        }

        public void setLogindate(java.sql.Date logindate) {
            this.logindate = logindate;
        }

        public String getLogintime() {
            return logintime;
        }

        public void setLogintime(String logintime) {
            this.logintime = logintime;
        }

        public String getLogouttime() {
            return logouttime;
        }

        public void setLogouttime(String logouttime) {
            this.logouttime = logouttime;
        }

        public String getLunch() {
            return lunch;
        }

        public void setLunch(String lunch) {
            this.lunch = lunch;
        }

        public String getAfterlunchlogin() {
            return afterlunchlogin;
        }

        public void setAfterlunchlogin(String afterlunchlogin) {
            this.afterlunchlogin = afterlunchlogin;
        }

        public String getAfterlunchlogout() {
            return afterlunchlogout;
        }

        public void setAfterlunchlogout(String afterlunchlogout) {
            this.afterlunchlogout = afterlunchlogout;
        }

        public String getTask() {
            return task;
        }

        public void setTask(String task) {
            this.task = task;
        }

        public String getTotal() {
            return total;
        }

        public void setTotal(String total) {
            this.total = total;
        }

        public String getOvertime() {
            return overtime;
        }

        public void setOvertime(String overtime) {
            this.overtime = overtime;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "EmployeeBean [empid=" + empid + ",logindate=" + logindate + ", logintime=" + logintime+ ", logouttime=" + logouttime + ", lunch=" + lunch+ ", afterlunchlogin=" + afterlunchlogin+ ", afterlunchlogout=" + afterlunchlogout+ ", task=" + task+ ", total=" + total+ ",overtime=" + overtime+ "]";
        }

    }
```

I dont know how to make employeebean to list type... pelase check the Timesheetservlet and timesheetdao.

please help me to insert 5 rows in database.

thanks!

Comment: Please check this link..it may be helpful to you.
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355046/java-insert-multiple-rows-into-mysql-with-preparedstatement)

Comment: @Naren thanks for replying... but as u see in I'm using bean class, jdbc, session & servlet.. And i don't know how to implement that addbatch here... I'm sorry if I'm being stupid!can you please help me to do that...

Comment: @Naren I have updated my code please check and help me to solve the errors.

Comment: @Naren thanks for editing my code... but still its have the same error in TimeSheetDao... Please have a look

Comment: have you got success in 1-row insertion ? i mean if yes then i can directly give you logic for multiple row insertion other wise i have to go what's went wrong's investigation ?

Comment: @Mr.VishalJGajera  I have Edited the for you  success in 1-row insertion please check it and help me! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your jsp to have different names for the different rows.
and also changed the serverlet code to read and build the list of employee bean.
 once you do these changes you can use the logic mentioned by the chrisI08 abovve. 
timesheet.jsp.

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  

<title>Timesheet Page</title>  
</head>  
<body>  

<form action="TimeSheetServlet" method="post">
    <fieldset style="width: 90%">  
        <legend>Timesheet</legend>   
        <table> 
            <thead><tr><th>Employee ID</th><th>Date</th><th>Time In</th><th>Time Out</th><th>Lunch</th><th>After Lunch Time in</th><th>After Lunch Time out</th><th>Task Description</th><th>Total Hours</th><th>Overtime</th> </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="empid1" required="required" /></td>   
                    <td><input type="date" id="date" name="logindate1" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="start" name="logintime1" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="end" name="logouttime1" required="required" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="time" class="lunch" name="lunch1" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="startafterlunch"  name="afterlunchlogin1" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout1" required="required" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="textarea" name="1" required="required" /></td>
                    <td><input type="time" class="totalTime" name="total1" /></td>
                    <td><input type="time" class="overTime" name="overtime1" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>  
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="empid2" required="required" /></td>   
                    <td><input type="date" id="date" name="logindate2" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="start" name="logintime2" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="end" name="logouttime2" required="required" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="time" class="lunch" name="lunch2" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="startafterlunch"  name="afterlunchlogin2" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout2" required="required" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="textarea" name="task2" required="required" /></td>
                    <td><input type="time" class="totalTime" name="total2" /></td>
                    <td><input type="time" class="overTime" name="overtime2" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>  
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="empid3" required="required" /></td>   
                    <td><input type="date" id="date" name="logindate3" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="start" name="logintime3" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="end" name="logouttime3" required="required" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="time" class="lunch" name="lunch3" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="startafterlunch"  name="afterlunchlogin3" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout3" required="required" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="textarea" name="task" required="required" /></td>
                    <td><input type="time" class="totalTime" name="total3" /></td>
                    <td><input type="time" class="overTime" name="overtime3" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>  
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="empid4" required="required" /></td>   
                    <td><input type="date" id="date" name="logindate4" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="start" name="logintime4" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="end" name="logouttime4" required="required" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="time" class="lunch" name="lunch4" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="startafterlunch"  name="afterlunchlogin4" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout4" required="required" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="textarea" name="task" required="required" /></td>
                    <td><input type="time" class="totalTime" name="total4" /></td>
                    <td><input type="time" class="overTime" name="overtime4" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>  
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="empid5" required="required" /></td>   
                    <td><input type="date" id="date" name="logindate5" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="start" name="logintime5" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="end" name="logouttime5" required="required" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="time" class="lunch" name="lunch5" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="startafterlunch"  name="afterlunchlogin5" required="required" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="time" class="endafterlunch" name="afterlunchlogout5" required="required" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="textarea" name="task5" required="required" /></td>
                    <td><input type="time" class="totalTime" name="total5" /></td>
                    <td><input type="time" class="overTime" name="overtime5" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>  
            </tbody>
        </table>  
    </fieldset>      
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a>
</body>  
</html>
```

servlet:

```
List<EmployeeBean> ebList=  ArrayList<EmployeeBean>();
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        EmployeeBean eb = new EmployeeBean();
         eb.setEmpid(Emp_id);


         Date logindate = new java.sql.Date(formatter.parse(request.getParameter("logindate"+i)).getTime());
          eb.setLogindate((java.sql.Date) logindate);


      //String Date=request.getParameter("logindate");    
      String LoginTime=request.getParameter("logintime"+i);
      eb.setLogintime(LoginTime);
      eb.setLogouttime(request.getParameter("logouttime"+i));
       eb.setLunch(request.getParameter("lunch"+i));
       eb.setAfterlunchlogin(request.getParameter("afterlunchlogin"+i));
       eb.setAfterlunchlogout(request.getParameter("afterlunchlogout"+i));
       eb.setTask(request.getParameter("task"+i));
        eb.setTotal(request.getParameter("total"+i));
       eb.setOvertime(request.getParameter("overtime"+i));
    }
    TimeSheetDao.insert(ebList);
```

Note: I have not compiled this code.you may need to change few things.

Comment: thanks for editing my code... but still its have the same error in TimeSheetDao... Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

You need to use batch inserts: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/  Look at "SQL Injection Safe Batch" section.  I have modified the TimeSheetDao.insert method as below:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class TimeSheetDao {
  // this sql string can be static final  
  public static final String sql= "insert into logintable values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

   public static int insert(List<EmployeeBean> employees) throws Exception {     

    Connection connection = new getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

    try {
        for (EmployeeBean employee: employees) {

            // set parameters here
            ps.setDate(2,new Date(eb.getLogindate().getTime()));
            ps.setString(3,eb.getLogintime());  
            ps.setString(4,eb.getLogouttime()); 
            ps.setString(5,eb.getLunch());
            ps.setString(6,eb.getAfterlunchlogin());  
            ps.setString(7,eb.getAfterlunchlogout()); 
            ps.setString(8,eb.getTask());
            ps.setString(9,eb.getTotal());
            ps.setString(10,eb.getOvertime());
            ps.addBatch();

        }

        ps.executeBatch();

    } finally {
        ps.close();
        connection.close();
    }         
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying... but as u see in I'm using bean class, jdbc, session & servlet.. And i don't know how to implement that addbatch here... I'm sorry if I'm being stupid! can you please help me to do that...

Comment: I have modified the TimeSheetDao.insert method to take a List<EmployeeBean> as a parameter. This should be enough to give you a direction to go

Comment: I have updated my code please check and help me to solve the errors.