# Writing array values into SQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, arrays, database

Looking for some help for writing array values into one of my tables within my sql database.
The array has already calculated all the values, and I want to insert these values into my database. However when I run the code I'm getting an error message stating "An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Parameter '@PE' has already been defined."

It says the same for each parameter if I remove the one before it.

I'm not quite sure whats going on as I've used this code in another form for writing stuff into a database and that works fine! Any help would be great.

My code is,

try

```
        {
            string myconnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=1234";
            MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(myconnection);
            MySqlDataAdapter MyDataAdaptor = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            MyDataAdaptor.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * lossdatabase.forecasttable;", myconn);
            MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(MyDataAdaptor);
            myconn.Open();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=1234; ";
        string query = " insert into lossdatabase.forecasttable (PE, Production_Time, Potential) VALUES(@PE, @Production_Time, @Potential;";



        MySqlConnection conLossDB = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdLossDB = new MySqlCommand(query, conLossDB);


        for (int i=0; i<366; i++)
        {
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PE", textBox2.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Production_Time", forecast[i,2]);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Potential", forecast[i,3]);


        }




        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conLossDB.Open();
            myReader = cmdLossDB.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Forecast Results Saved");


            while (myReader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: `select * FROM lossdatabase.forecasttable;` You forgot your FROM there.

Comment: and your insert query is lacking an `)` at the end too.

Comment: You need to move your "MySqlCommand cmdLossDB = ..." line into the loop, and also execute your query in the loop.

Comment: Create a mysql prepared statement and add batch like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355046/java-insert-multiple-rows-into-mysql-with-preparedstatement

Answer (score 0):

If understood your code, you're adding a new parameter for every element in your array. You should add the values to a variable in the `for` loop, and add the parameter once, after the `for` loop ends something like this:

```
MySqlDataReader myReader;
try
{
    conLossDB.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < 366; i++)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmdLossDB = new MySqlCommand(query, conLossDB);
        cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PE", textBox2.Text);
        cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Production_Time", forecast[i, 2]);
        cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Potential", forecast[i, 3]);
        cmdLossDB.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Forecast Results Saved");

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I assumed forecast is an array of strings, you may need to cast for different types. You must also fix the errors pointed by @Jens and @David_001.

Comment: I've modified my code based on your suggestion above, as well as the the two comments from Jens and David_001.

I'm not getting a fatal error encountered during command execution. Which must be coming from the last part of my code with the MySqlDataReader but again, not sure how to tackle that? @Ricardo Pontual

Comment: I've updated my code, check out. I replaced `ExecuteReader` by `ExecuteNonQuery` since it's an insert command. Now it's up to you