# JDBC : Batch insert not inserting value to database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have to execute multiple insert queries using JDBC for which I am trying to execute batch statement. Everything works fine in my code but when i try to see values in the table, the table is empty.
Here is the code :

```
SessionImpl sessionImpl = (SessionImpl) getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
    Connection conn = (Connection) sessionImpl.connection();

    Statement statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

    for (String query : queries) {
        statement.addBatch(query);
    }
    statement.executeBatch();
    statement.close();
    conn.close();
```

And the

```
List<String> queries
```

contains insert queries like:

```
insert into demo values (null,'Sharmzad','10006','http://demo.com','3 Results','some values','$44.00','10006P2','No Ratings','No Reviews','Egypt','Duration: 8 hours','tour','Day Cruises');
```

And the table structure is like:

```
create table demo ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,supplierName varchar(200),supplierId varchar(200),supplierUrl varchar(200),totalActivities varchar(200),activityName varchar(200),activityPrice varchar(200),tourCode varchar(200),starRating varchar(200),totalReviews varchar(200),geography varchar(200),duration varchar(200),category varchar(200),subCategory varchar(200));
```

No exception is thrown anywhere but no value is inserted. Can someone explain?

Comment: Remove 'null' from insert query

Comment: If i remove null (which is for auto-increment id), i get an exception of "Not enough column values"

Comment: I can't see `conn.commit()` did you configure _"autocommit"_ for your connection

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355046/java-insert-multiple-rows-into-mysql-with-preparedstatement), might help!

Comment: primary key had default not null constraint and I just wonder why your insert query don't throw error message like ERROR:  null value in column "ID" violates not-null constraint.

Comment: I guess i need to commit the connection. I haven't done that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most JDBC drivers use `autocommit`, but some of them do not. If you don't know, you should use either `.setAutoCommit(true)` before the transaction or `.commit()` after it..

Answer (score 1):

Could be a transaction issue. Perhaps you're not committing your transaction? If so, then it is normal not to see anything in the database.

You can check if this is the case by running a client in READ_UNCOMMITTED transaction mode, right after `.executeBatch();` (but before `close()`) and see if there are any rows.

Answer (score 1):

You don't should assign a value to ID add supply all the others columns name

```
 insert into demo 
 (
 supplierName 
,supplierId 
,supplierUrl 
,totalActivities 
,activityName 
,activityPrice 
,tourCode 
,starRating 
,totalReviews 
,geography 
,duration 
,category 
,subCategory 
)
values (
'Sharmzad'
,'10006'
,'http://demo.com'
,'3 Results'
,'some values'
,'$44.00'
,'10006P2'
,'No Ratings'
,'No Reviews'
,'Egypt'
,'Duration: 8 hours
','tour'
,'Day Cruises'
);
```

and add commit to your code

Comment: is it necessary to add (
 supplierName 
,supplierId 
,supplierUrl 
,totalActivities 
,activityName 
,activityPrice 
,tourCode 
,starRating 
,totalReviews 
,geography 
,duration 
,category 
,subCategory 
)  before mentioning values?

Comment: @roger_that  If you don't assign all the columns .. you must inform the query which column match the related value.. and this is done by an explicit naming

Comment: Did that. Nothing happening. Do i need to commit the connection as well?

Comment: Yeah. I had to commit. Thanks.

Comment: @roger_that   . .. i have update the asnwer ..with the tips for commit