# StackOverflowException in an attempt to save to database

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring

I have some issue and what's special - project worked correctly around 14 days and ever today, 30 minutes ago, I lucky launch him one time...and after that again have an issue.

For begin I want to add is the proof that everything worked half an hour ago:

[image]

We can see - run time for executing all process: 107411ms(107sec)

---

So.
I developed spring project, which works with database using JpaRepository interface implementing.

### Have issue, when I try to sent a post method into Controller from console:

```
curl -d '{"explorerId":'24', "turnOff":true}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/vdtw
```

---

**Variant 1**

---

- "variant 1" (with @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) annotations in entity (showed in **Structure** section))

program starts, and after few second returns error in console:

> {"timestamp":"2018-09-18T10:01:08.343+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal
>   Server Error","message":"No message available","path":"/vdtw"}

In IDEA console throws error: **StackOverflowException: null*
with preview:

> *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
>
> 2018-09-18 13:01:08.306 ERROR 25853 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

prinscrn:

[image]

---

**Variant 2**
(with fetch = FetchType.LAZY, no CascadType set)

---

In this case, program works normally, but so long time (10+ minutes):

> Generate vacancy description to word, parse 14885 words. Time: 621304

---

**Questions:**

- Why did the program work normally for 14 days and is now starting to
  throw StackOverflowException?
- How to optimize the structure for faster storage of entities in the
  database?

### Structure:

**The object stored in the database:**

```
@Entity(name = "vacancy_desc_to_words")
public class VacancyDescriptionToWords {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@JoinColumn(name = "vacancy_description_id")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private VacancyDescription vacancyDescription;

@JoinColumn(name = "words_id")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadType.ALL);
//------------------Second variant--------------------------- 
//@ManyToOne
private Words words;
}
```

**Linked by ManyToOne entity:**

```
@Entity(name = "words")
public class Words {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "word", unique = true)
private String word;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "words", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, CascadType.ALL)

//---------------------Second variant----------------------
//@OneToMany(mappedBy = "words", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

private Set<VacancyDescriptionToWords> vacancyDescriptionToWordsSet;

//getters/setters
}
```

**Pom.xml:**

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Place in the code where the problem occurs

```
        List<VacancyDescriptionToWords> vdtwList = VDTWService.parseAndGenerateNewDescToWords(vacancyDescriptions);

//--------------- exception string ----------------------
        VDTWService.saveAll(vdtwList);
```

---

**Saving list of entities way:**

```
public void saveAll(List<VacancyDescriptionToWords> vdtwList) {
    vdtwRepository.saveAll(vdtwList);
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface VDTWRepository extends JpaRepository<VacancyDescriptionToWords, Long> {
}
```

---

Comment: This is too much information in my opinion.

Comment: Can you provide minimal code with your error ?

Comment: It is not possible to guess when I give you have little information when it is too much. If you target only to decrement of question...

Comment: In my opinion the cause of this error may be bad recursive call. You may want to test you application.

Comment: @Lokesh The exception runs exactly in the line where I store the list of objects in the database. There is called only the JpaRepository method    <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> var1);

Comment: What's in `parseAndGenerateNewDescToWords` method?

Comment: "Why did the program work normally for 14 days and is now starting to throw StackOverflowException?" i assume the data size in the database did grow in the 14 days?

Comment: "How to optimize the structure for faster storage of entities in the database?" Something like this i guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355046/java-insert-multiple-rows-into-mysql-with-preparedstatement

Comment: @NickSavenia, it just creat List of entities - takes some data from database, gaenerate list of VacancyDescriptionToWord, count - 14000+. Works correctly.

Comment: @ RaymondNijland is a good question, I also looked in this direction, but no - I dropped the database and it did not solve anything.